# Pulling last week M-F range from any current week day

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

```
SELECT d.i_EmpID as 'EmpID',m.c_EmployeeFirstName as 'First Name', 
m.c_employeeLastName as 'Last Name', d.c_date as 'Date', d.c_A as 'A', d.c_M 
as 'M', d.c_P as 'P', d.c_lp as 'Lp'
,'School' as Company
FROM [table1].[dbo].[tbl_daily] d
inner join [table2].[dbo].[tbl_emp] m
on d.[i_EmpID] = m.[i_EmpID]
where left(c_date, 2)=datepart(month, getdate()-1) and 
right(c_date,4)=datepart(year,getdate()-1) and substring(c_date, 
4,2)=datepart(day,getdate()-3)
```

Hello,

I am trying to pull last week date range past off of current date. Right now I have 5 separate queries unioned for the end of the code (day,getdate()-3) to be the other 5 days in the week (I am looking for Monday to Friday). This is essentially my query without the other 4 unions to be able to pull Monday to Friday and I already this is not the best way at all to do it and in fact it doesn't even work today.

I am able to get this done in MySQL because it has a built in week function and I can just pull last week, however I can't figure out how to pull last week in SQL because the language is different. My issue is that my code worked yesterday, however due to the fact it is subtracting the days, on Tuesday to Friday, it won't work/it doesn't work. I am by no means an expert with using dates in SQL and I am at a loss.

I know there has to be a better way, I've spent about 4 hours reading various guides and examples but I cannot seem to find an example of specifically what I am looking for.

Long and short of it is that I am trying pull last week (example: 9/24 to 9/28) any day of the current week that I run it. So even if I run my report on Friday(10/5), I am able to see 9/24 to 9/28 and the similarly next week to be able to pull 10/1 to 10/5 of this week. Those are the tables and columns I am pulling. Also, if it matters, this is not a school project but a work related project I was tasked with.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advanced.

edit: Sample Data:

```
EID     First   Last    Date          A  M  P   LP        Company
5303    Kent    Grit    09/25/2018    9  44 54   3        Company 1
6890    Lola    Grif    09/28/2018    5  4  3             Company 1
6272    Paul    Hammer  09/26/2018    1  2  4    4        Company 1
6273    Joe     Hammer  09/24/2018    11 8  7             Company 1
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: I updated with a brief sample data that should be returned from the query.

Comment: To paraphrase; you want a calculation, with a single date as an input, which returns the date of the immediately preceding Friday, and then also the Monday immediately preceding that?

Comment: Yes. If I run the report on 10/2, I want to be able to see 9/24 to 9/28. If I run the report again on 10/5 to look at something, I still want to be able to see 9/24 to 9/28. Then on 10/8 when I run the report, I want to be able to see 10/2 to 10/5 and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
...
WHERE
  CAST(c_date AS DATE) >= DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)
  AND
  CAST(c_date AS DATE) < DATEADD(DAY, +5, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0))
```

It will pull last Monday at midnight and last Saturday at midnight (so you get the last second of Friday in your result set) from Sunday through Saturday.

**Edit**: Added the `CAST` per comments.

Comment: Ok, I figured out my problem (besides not knowing much about dates). The problem is the date field is not stored as a datetime. Its stored as a nchar10 and I don't have the ability to alter the table. I should be able to cast or convert the field to datetime, yeah?

Comment: That's right. Modified my answer to reflect a `CAST`.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished with `dateadd` and `datepart` functions with some arithmetic.

```
with dates(dt) as (select '2018-10-02' union all
                   select '2018-10-01' union all
                   select '2018-10-03' union all
                   select '2018-10-04' union all
                   select '2018-10-05' union all
                   select '2018-10-06' union all
                   select '2018-10-11' 
                  ) 
--Actual query to be executed by replacing the table name
select dt,
dateadd(day,-datepart(dw,cast(dt as date))-5,cast(dt as date)) as strt,
dateadd(day,-datepart(dw,cast(dt as date))-1,cast(dt as date)) as ed
from dates --replace this with the table being used
```

Comment: The report needs to be able to sustain itself. By using those dates, would I need to add every date for the fiscal year?

Comment: that is just an example to show how it works. replace the table name with your table.

Comment: @David The dates in this answer are example inputs.  They don't form part of the calculation.  You could use GETDATE() as an input instead.